# How to change a nav-link pill with a link?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, nav-pills

I have this Bootstrap Nav-pills - with 2 tabs:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill kt-portlet__space-x" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#menu11"><span> TAB1</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#menu21"><span>TAB2</span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Inside TAB2 I have a button and I need to change to TAB1 onclick. It's possible?

I try this:

```
<input type="button" data-toggle="pill" href="#menu11" value="GO TO TAB1">
```

Opens TAB1 - but.. Does not ACTIVE tab1 (the "active border" still on tab2) - and when I return to Tab2 - doesn't works anymore..

any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

I got:

```
$(function(){

    $('#opencard').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#deck a[href="#menu11"]').tab('show');
    })

})
```

- create a Button with ID=OpenCard
- update  with ID=Deck

works fine! :D

Answer (score 0):

You will need some JS to accomplish what you are after. You will want to remove the `data-toggle="pill"` attribute that you have on your button from your example. `#theButton` in this example is the id of the button you want to use to switch tabs.

```
$('#theButton').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#menu11').tab('show');
});
```

As a side note you might was to add a few accessibility items to each `nav-link`:

```
role="tab" aria-controls="menu21" aria-selected="false"
```

Replace `aria-controls` and `aria-selected` with appropriate values for each tab.